# FPS issue: Asus TUF FX505 gaming laptop

Tags: windows-10

Before I begin my specs are stated here -

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9300H CPU @ 2.40GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 GDDR5 @ 4GB (128bit) 
RAM: 8.00GB (7.85 GB usable) 
OS: Windows 10 64-bit

Whenever I play games such as titanfall 2 or fallout new vegas on my windows login (which is the administrator profile) my games run at a decent 40-60 FPS. However my sister has games such as wolfquest 3: Anniversary edition and The Isle on her windows profile. When she tries to run her games, they seem FPS capped. The isle will at random cap itself at 15 to 30 FPS and wolfquest will cap itself at 14 FPS or lower. Wolfquest for instance ran at a flawless 60fps on the highest setting and so did the isle at one point in time, but now shes having capped fps issues with her 2 higher end games whereas when I log into my profile and use my games, they run decently at 40 to 60fps. Is there any kind of setting within the laptop that throttles other users hardware usage or some administrator setting that allows me to have higher performance than other users? Or maybe it's a hardware, software, or system setting? I doubt it's a lack of needed hardware because other games using the same hardware run at maximum performance.

Comment: Do you log out of your profile when your sister tries to play? If things are still running in your profile, it will affect the resources she has available.

Comment: Open the Task Manager using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Esc` and check the Performance tab to see the utilization of your CPU, Memory, and GPU. If nothing seems strange then have her launch a problematic game while keeping the Task Manager open. After a few minutes close or `Alt`+`Tab` out of the game and check the graphs in the Task Manager. You can also download and use GPU-z if you need continuous logging to a file.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem usually called stuttering. ASUS products should have "adaptive syncronize" feature, whatever the processor is, intel or AMD, you can try to turn it on with graphic software like this [guide to turn on adaptive sync](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1042713)

Comment: Can you provide an English source?